# Descartes folium

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, cubics, plane-curves

The geometry of Descartes' folium, $x^3+y^3=3axy$ has been well studied. Can someone tell me which geometric property characterizes the following cubic curve:
$$bx^3+y^3=3axy$$
The previous curve is a cubic curve with a node at the origin and their tangent directions are de coordenate axis... (the property I'm looking for is in terms of the coefficients a,b)

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange.  Is this a homework problem? You may avoid downvotes if you follow the guidelines for [good questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), specifically what avenues you've explored so far and what your motivation is.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your coordinates and the coefficient:
$$bx^3+y^3=3axy$$
$$(\sqrt[3]{b}x)^3+y^3=3a\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{b}}(\sqrt[3]{b}x)y$$
$$\sqrt[3]{b}x\mapsto x_1\qquad y\mapsto y_1\qquad \frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{b}}\mapsto a_1$$
So you have a the usual form:
$$x_1^3+y_1^3=3a_1x_1y_1$$

So if in general you know a property of type:
$$f(x,y,a)=0$$
for the first curve, you can transform it in an equivalent property of type:
$$f\left(\sqrt[3]{b}x_1,y_1,\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{b}}\right)=0$$
for the second curve.